# Issue in firing multiple search requests in elasticsearch

Tags: java, exception, search, elasticsearch

I have copied 20 index from an elasticsearch instance to  a new instance. After that when I started firing search queries in the new instance from my code, after 20-30 calls I'm getting error:

```
{[aRGdCWK2QsyfvgGJLt6xrA][quanteye_ing][1]: EsRejectedExecutionException[rejected execution (queue capacity 1000) 
                                            on org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23@29fdcd0e]}
```

How to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

This error typically occurs when elasticsearch cluster cannot keep up with the search traffic. This is basically an internal protections mechanism that saves elasticsearch from overload. When this error is returned a properly behaving client application should temporary stop executing searches and wait for the elasticsearch instance to recover. If this situation occurs too often, increasing the capacity of the cluster by adding more nodes might be necessary.

If the problem is caused by short spikes in the client traffic you can also alleviate the issue by increasing the thread pool queue size:

`threadpool.search.queue_size: 2000`

This can be done in `elasticsearch.yml` file or dynamically. However, this solution is not going to work with sustained heavy traffic that exceeds the cluster capacity.